# Yarn executable was not detected in the system while deploying rails 6 to AWS Beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, webpack, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, yarnpkg

Trying to deploy Ruby on Rails app on AWS Beanstalk. Ruby version is 2.6.6 and Rails version is 5.2.3. RDS and other setup is done but when I don `eb deploy` it gives an error while assets precompilation. Error is that Yarn not detected. In this app I have `webpack` gem also so due to this yarn needed

```
+ su -s /bin/bash -c 'bundle exec /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/scripts/check-for-rake-task.rb assets:precompile' webapp
  `/home/webapp` is not a directory.
  Bundler will use `/tmp/bundler20200726-3166-q5qdvj3166' as your home directory temporarily.
  + '[' false == true ']'
  + su -s /bin/bash -c 'bundle exec rake assets:precompile' webapp
  `/home/webapp` is not a directory.
  Bundler will use `/tmp/bundler20200726-3256-1yqrnzx3256' as your home directory temporarily.
  Yarn executable was not detected in the system.
  Download Yarn at https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install
  rake aborted!
  SassC::SyntaxError: Error: File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.
          on line 16:1 of app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss
  >> @import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
  
     ^
  /var/app/ondeck/app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss:16
  Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
  (See full trace by running task with --trace) (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)


[2020-07-26T15:41:34.604Z] ERROR [2838]  : Command CMD-AppDeploy failed!
[2020-07-26T15:41:34.604Z] INFO  [2838]  : Command processor returning results: 
{"status":"FAILURE","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"FAILURE","msg":"(TRUNCATED)...ootstrap.\n        on line 16:1 of app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss\n>> @import \"bootstrap/scss/bootstrap\";\n\n   ^\n/var/app/ondeck/app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss:16\nTasks: TOP => assets:precompile\n(See full trace by running task with --trace). \nHook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/11_asset_compilation.sh failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI","returncode":1,"events":[]}],"truncated":"true"}
```

Although in .ebextensions I created a config file yarn.config

```
 01_node_get:
cwd: /tmp
command: 'sudo curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo bash -'

02_node_install:
cwd: /tmp
command: 'sudo yum -y install nodejs'

03_yarn_get:
cwd: /tmp
# don't run the command if yarn is already installed (file /usr/bin/yarn exists)
test: '[ ! -f /usr/bin/yarn ] && echo "yarn not installed"'
command: 'sudo wget https://dl.yarnpkg.com/rpm/yarn.repo -O /etc/yum.repos.d/yarn.repo'

04_yarn_install:
cwd: /tmp
test: '[ ! -f /usr/bin/yarn ] && echo "yarn not installed"'
command: 'sudo yum -y install yarn'
```

How I can fix that issue?

Answer (score 0):

the issue is with the path of @import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

it needs to be

"node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

the path should be relative to the root

Comment: @import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

Comment: @import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap"; 
basically those are inside node_modules

Comment: ok then the @import should be ""node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap"

Comment: but in rails we not push node_module ...it will build with assets:precompile